drawPixmap add to image some space
There are same size and pozitions elements but when I draw Pixmap image I think it add some spaces in but if I draw rect with drawRect I acchive what I want :

 painter.drawRect(int(75 - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                                      int(80 - self.original_box.height() / 2), 150, 180)

it gives rect.
But it draw wrong size and position image:
painter.drawPixmap(int(75 - self.original_box.width() / 2 ),
                                 int( 80- self.original_box.height() / 2),
                               self.original_box)

Why this happening?

Please provide a valid [mre].
